# Avoid overlap for a set of fixed nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 to draw a graph where the nodes are all fixed.
In my use case the nodes are not of the same size and they are connected using edges.
It is similar to the graph here - http://linkedjazz.org/network/
I am trying to place the nodes over the oval shape.
Here there happens a lot overlap between nodes which i want to avoid.
Is there anyway i can see if there are 2 nodes overlapping and adjust the location with my logic , so that i can place the nodes in a rightly oval shape ?